# Read text file line by line and use data for input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading in a text file where I know what each line of the file is.

For example, the first line is a starting coordinate pair that is in the format {"x":9,"y":9} and the second line is a end coordinate pair.

There exists global variable `var startCoord = {"x": startX, "y": startY};`

How can I pull the x and y from the file to set as the new `startCoord.x` and `startCoord.y` respectively?

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8h3u2vxd/)

Example of text file:

```
{"x":9,"y":9}
{"x":4,"y":104}
{"x":124,"y":51}
{"x":92,"y":65}
{"x":113,"y":31}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON in each line into an object in order to access properties like `x` and `y`. To do so, simply change

```
var obj = lines[0] // or whatever index you want to parse
```

to

```
var obj = JSON.parse(lines[0])
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8h3u2vxd/1/

---

I would also optimise your `for` loop like so

```
const lines = this.result.split('\n');
if (lines.length > 0 && lines.length % 2 > 0) {
  throw 'Invalid data format'
}
for (let i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i += 2) {
  let startObj = JSON.parse(lines[i])
  let endObj = JSON.parse(lines[i + 1])
  // and so on  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8h3u2vxd/2/